# jqPivot totalText: option totalText: "{0} {1}". Can replace {1} by label of aggregate instead of member?

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid, jqpivot

I'm using jqGrid with the jqPivot.

My problem is totalText of jqPivot.
In document: totalText: "{0} {1}"

> The totalText option contains the template with {0} and {1} which will be
>   replaced to aggregates[i].aggregator and aggregates[i].member

Can I replace {1} by aggregates[i].label instead of aggregates[i].member?

I use free jqGrid version 4.13.7

The pivot options:

```js
var pvConfig = {
        footerTotals: true,   
        footerAggregator: "sum",
        totals: true,
        totalHeader: "Tổng cộng",    
        totalText: "{0} {1}", 
        useColSpanStyle: true,
        xDimension: [
            { dataName: 'ten_vt', label: 'Tên vật tư', width: 150, },
        ],
        yDimension: [
            { dataName: 'ma_ct_gd', totalHeader: '' },
        ],
        aggregates: [
            { member: 'du_dau', aggregator: 'count', summaryType: 'count', label: 'Dư đầu' },
            { member: 'du_cuoi', aggregator: 'sum', summaryType: 'sum', label: 'Dư cuối' }
        ]
    }
```

And the result like

[image]

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? You should post the code, which you use to call `jqPivot` or to post the demo, which reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Oleg, I want the totalText like "sum Dư đầu", "sum Dư cuối", but not "sum du_dau", "sum du_cuoi". Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `totalText` as callback function instead of the template `"{0} {1}"`. Try to use

```js
totalText: function (options) {
    return options.aggregate.aggregator + " - " + options.aggregate.label;
}
```

Additionally I would strictly recommend to upgrade to the latest **released** version of free jqGrid. It's currently the version **4.14.0**. There are no version 4.13.7, but it was **preliminary** version `"4.13.7-pre"`, which have to be specified with the build date. The code, which you use could be unstable. I make the build on any changes in GitHub code. Thus you use currently some unstable version from GitHub with some state between 4.13.6 and 4.14.0. In any way, it's supported only the latest released version (4.14.0) or the latest code (today state) from GitHub.